# How to switch between the X sessions by only-using the command line?

Tags: linux

Since I am running the X session in the VirtualBox, as a result, whether I type `ctrl+alt` + `f7`or`f12` all the commands are executed on the host, not on the guest.So, I am not able to switch between the X sessions.
All i can do is start a new session by--

`startx -- :$num`

but how to go back to the previous sessions from the cli.

So is there a command for switching between the X sessions?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know in which tty you are running: `who`.

Then you can switch to tty 3 for example: `sudo chvt 3`

Then go back to the first one using `sudo chvt <your_first_tty>`

Comment: it changes the virtual terminal but I wanted to change the X session